# Python XX instance has no attribute YY

Tags: python

I have this noob error,

```
   l = instanciaHagale.multiplicaMethod() AttributeError: Hagale instance has no attribute 'multiplicaMethod'
```

here my code:

```
class Hagale :
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a 
        print self.a 

        self.sumaleAlgo = self.a+34543 #variable creada on the fly!

        def multiplicaMethod (self):

            return 'self.cuadradoReal'
            #self.cuadradoReal = self.a * 2

instanciaHagale = Hagale(345)

print instanciaHagale.sumaleAlgo #acceso a las variables de mi objeto! 

l = instanciaHagale.multiplicaMethod()

print l
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    def __init__(self, a):
        # ...

        def multiplicaMethod (self):
```

The last `def` is indented wrong. Outdent it so it is at the same level as `def __init__(self, a):`, like this:

```
class Hagale(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a 
        print self.a 
        self.sumaleAlgo = self.a+34543 #variable creada on the fly!

    def multiplicaMethod (self): # <-- moved to the left
        return 'self.cuadradoReal'
```

Also note that your code uses [classic classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes). That's probably not want you want, but it's an easy fix - simply inherit from `object`.

Answer (score 3):

your `multiplicaMethod()` is defined inside of the `__init__` method. it's indented too far.  move it to the left so that its inside the class instead.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplicaMethod should be indented left. Now it is a local function inside **init**.